# yii2 ActiveRecord multiple where

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2

I want to make multiple where query, with both `<` and `=` operators.

With multiple `=` operators it goes like:

```
Model::find()->where([
    'param1' => 0,
    'param2' => 0,
])->all();
```

With one `<` operator

```
Model::find()->where([
    '<', 'param1', 0
])->all();
```

How can I apply both these conditions in **one** `where` array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Model::find()->where([
    'and',
    [
        'param1' => 0,
        'param2' => 0,
    ],
    ['<', 'param1', 0]
])->all();
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use  a combination of where andWhere

```
   Model::find()->where([param1' => 0 ])
          ->andWhere(['>','param2' , 0])->all();
```

adding the operator to you clause  see operator format

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html